# Why I cannot shutdown or reboot from lightdm?

Tags: 13.04, lightdm

I am unable to reboot or shutdown from lightdm. When I click on the button "Shutdown" or "Reboot" in the pop-ups simply nothing happens.

I cannot find nothing wrong in `/var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`

Anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe there is another user logged in ? A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/861171) for this behavior exists already.

Comment: No other users active. It happens even after a fresh reboot. Thanks.

Comment: Then I would suggest to report a bug `ubuntu-bug lightdm` and let the developers to deal with it.

Comment: Ok...sorry for the stupid question...is `ubuntu-bug` a mailing list?

Answer (score 0):

**Try to reconfigure lightdm, it may fix your issue**

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list.
- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**Method 2:**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like *lightdm*):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then choose `gdm` from the list. And restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

Hope these methods might solve your issue. Reply for further assistance.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` tried but the problem is still there.
As to gdm concerns I'm not really taking into consideration to change the default display manager. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It depends on you!! Actually installing `gdm` will not change any settings, it will install one extra display manager, that's all. You can switch to any display manager at any time without any trouble. Just you have to run this command every time you want to switch: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. Believe me, you will never be in trouble.. :)

Comment: Not scared, simply I'd like to solve the problem instead that circumnavigate it. ;)

Comment: Okay! As your wish. But if you tried, it would help to find whether that bug was in `lightdm` or something else. You can later remove completely `gdm` by executing these commands: `sudo apt-get autoremove gdm` and `sudo apt-get --purge remove gdm`. Any way I marked your question as `Favorite` and also liked it so that it would attract other helper to find the solution.

Comment: Tried GDM, shutdown and reboot not working and I can't login either.

Comment: Can not log-in means?

Comment: That after I insert the password...nothing happens it just says me that I am connected...strange behaviour...but the session doesn't launch.

Comment: Ok. then switch to `lightdm` back. Here how you can switch: 
Press `ctrl+alt+f1` then login using your user name and password. Then run this command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and chose `lightdm` from the list and run : `sudo reboot`. Reply if you successfully changed to lightdm.

Comment: Yep I successfully reverted to lightdm.

Comment: Now it is clear that your problem is not because of `lightdm` right? I don't know exactly. But it may be because of your graphics card.

Comment: Hello I found the problem is an upstart task I written to make a permanent ssh tunnel. Apparently LightDM is not able to kill the task.

Comment: `start on net-device-up IFACE=wlan1 
stop on runlevel [01S6]

exec ssh -CND 8888 user@localhost -i MY_KEY`

Can you see something wrong?

Comment: No I'm not able to grasp it. Copy and paste same in google, hope you would get some help.